# Is update by select atomic for READ_COMMITED in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

Is following query atomic within READ_COMMITED transaction?

```sql
update my_table
 set
   owner = ?,
 where id = (
   select id from my_table
   where owner is null
   limit 1
 ) returning *
```

I run tests on local postgres instance and it seems to be atomic, but is this always the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each SQL statement in `READ COMMITTED` isolation level takes a snapshot of the database, so it and all its subqueries see a consistent version of the database.

But you are not safe from “lost updates”: it is possible that a concurrent transaction modifies a row between the start of the statement and the time the row is updated, so it could be that the row that is actually updated does not have `owner` set to NULL any more.

If you need to avoid that, add a `FOR UPDATE` clause in the subquery.